# Unable to store Image into internal storage directory

Tags: android, directory, storage, store

I wanted to create a folder and store image into the phone's internal storage. I tried using the code below to download an image from the url. It managed to load the image into imageView but unable to store and create folder in the internal storage. Plus I got no warning or error message. Any idea what's wrong code below?

```
        Bitmap bm = null;
        InputStream in;

            try{

                in = new java.net.URL("http://blogs.computerworld.com/sites/computerworld.com/files/u177/google-nexus-4.jpg").openStream();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(in));
                File mydir = this.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                mydir.mkdirs();
                File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);



            }
            catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_display);
  img.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Another question is that if I created in Internal storage will it appear in gallery as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have your bitmap `bm`:

```
FileOutputStream fos;

try {
    fos = openFileOutput("file_Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
}catch (Exception e){
...
}
```

will save your file to internal storage

Answer (score 1):

use the following:

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .toString() + File.separator
```

to get the directory and save the image.

Comment: I tried using this. Still it's not working. No idea why or how.

Comment: This has frustrated the hell out of me too. getExternalStorageDirectory() will return something like /storage/emulated/0/... when on some or only the Nexus devices that don't have external storage don't have that directory. It should be /storage/emulated/legacy/...! Why on my Nexus10 does it return a path that doesn't exist and is incorrect? Grrr...